# Using where clause in split_to_table in snowflake stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in a table which is separated by commas, hence I am using the split_to_table to get them as separate rows.

In addition I am also using a where clause in the SQL statement. I get an error saying unexpected ')'. I have tried multiple version of using the parameter in the where clause like +S_TBL+ and :1, but I get the same error.

When I hardcode the parameter to a value say where source_table= 'abc', then it works. But it is dynamically not picking the value. Is it an issue with the parenthesis here split_to_table(cols, ',')?

```
create or replace procedure merge_dynamic(S_TBL VARCHAR, T_TBL 
VARCHAR)
returns varchar
language javascript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$
var return_value= "";
var target_value= "TGT.";
var return_pk= "";
var target_pk= "TGT.";
var source_table= "";
var target_table= "";

var tables= "select source_table, target_table from project.reference.merge_info where source_table= '" +S_TBL+ "';";
var sql_split_col_name= "select y.value as split_value from project.reference.merge_info, LATERAL split_to_table(cols, ',') where source_table= '" +S_TBL+ "';";
var sql_split_pk_cols= "select x.value as split_value from project.reference.merge_info, LATERAL split_to_table(primary_cols, ',')x";


sql_res_tables= snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:tables});
rs_tables= sql_res_tables.execute();

while(rs_tables.next())
{
    source_table= rs_tables.getColumnValue(1);
    target_table= rs_tables.getColumnValue(2);
}
   
   
   
sql_res= snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sql_split_col_name});
rs_cols= sql_res.execute();
if(rs_cols.next())
{
    return_value+= rs_cols.getColumnValue(1);
    target_value+= rs_cols.getColumnValue(1);
}
while(rs_cols.next())
{
    return_value+= ', '
    return_value+= rs_cols.getColumnValue(1);
    target_value+= ', ';
    target_value+= "TGT."+rs_cols.getColumnValue(1);
}



  sql_res_pk= snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sql_split_pk_cols});
  rs_pk= sql_res_pk.execute();
  if(rs_pk.next())
  {
    return_pk+= rs_pk.getColumnValue(1);
    target_pk+= rs_pk.getColumnValue(1);
  }

   while(rs_pk.next())
   {
    return_pk+= ', ';
    return_pk+= rs_pk.getColumnValue(1);
    target_pk+= ', ';
    target_pk+= "TGT."+rs_pk.getColumnValue(1);
   }

  tbl_query= "merge into "+T_TBL+" TGT using " +S_TBL+ " src on hash(src. "+return_pk+")= hash("+target_pk+") when not matched then insert (" +target_value+ ") values ("+ return_value+ ")";
  tbl_res= snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:tbl_query});
  result= tbl_res.execute();
  result.next();
  col1= result.getColumnValue(1);

return col1;
$$;

call merge_dynamic('PROJECT.LAKE.LAKE_TABLE1', 'PROJECT.HUB.HUB_TABLE1');
```

Comment: Hi - please format your question so that it more readable e.g. format your SQL statements as code

Comment: I have put the entire code formatted. I basically get the error here. var sql_split_col_name= "select token as y from project.reference.merge_info(split_to_table(cols, ',')) where source_table= '" +S_TBL+ "';";

Comment: The line of code you mention in your comment doesn't exist in the code you've provided in your question

Comment: var sql_split_col_name= "select y.value as split_value from project.reference.merge_info, LATERAL split_to_table(cols, ',') where source_table= '" +S_TBL+ "';";
           This is the one I meant. It is there in the code in the declaration section.